# Is it possible to draw an equation based straight line in D3?

Tags: d3.js

I am new to D3.js, pardon me if my understanding is wrong.

I have an equation for a straight line in a log-log plot, Log(Y)=Log(C) + Log(X), C is constant and user defined.

Is there a way to draw the straight line in D3 purely from the equation?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No this isn't possible exactly as you'd like in D3. D3 is less about mathmatical calculation & visualization compared to other tools (R, MatLab) and is more about binding data sets to DOM and handling animation between data sets.

That being said, if you calculate the X and Y values for the equation then you can plot those values easily. I've seen D3 used like this, with input boxes for `C` and then plotting across a range.

Following your comment here's an example:

```
const C = 1;
const xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([0, 1000]); // pixels

const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 100])
    .range([0, 1000]);

const line = d3.line()
               .x(d => xScale(d))
               .y(d => yScale(Math.log(C) + Math.log(d)));

const values = [0, 50, 100];

d3.selectAll("path")
  .datum(values)
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "steelblue")
  .attr("d", line);
```

Note that the key to pumping in the equation is defining how to generate the `y` value given the `x` in the line generator, covered by this line:

```
.y(d => yScale(Math.log(C) + Math.log(d)))
```

Comment: What if C and X are user defined (x1 and x2 will be given), can D3 figure out Y (y1 and y2) and plot the line?

Comment: @ShadowWarrior I've added a pseduo-code example to illustrate how you could do this. You could drive the `X` values and the `C` in any way you wish (sliders/input boxes etc).

Comment: I will simply define C and X in the code (no sliders/input boxes etc). Thank you for doing it, can you please put the code in jsfiddle or repl.it? I am using D3 v3 and having difficulty to make the code to work.

Comment: @ShadowWarrior This is just pseudocode to give you an example. If you've a specific problem then feel free to ask for some clarification here, or in another question. I'm afraid I don't have the time right now to create a fully working solution.

Comment: @ShadowWarrior an `svg:path` is a moving line rather than a straight one. If you want just a straight line you could indeed just calculate the `x1`, `x2, `y1, and `y2` yourself. Remember to push the calculations through the `xScale` and `yScale` functions though to translate to screen co-ordinates.

Comment: @ShadowWarrior if this helped you please consider accepting the answer. If there's more I can elaborate on then let me know.

Comment: Apologies, I am still not clear why D3 can not plot lines based on equation but can plot path.

Comment: `D3` is not plotting either the paths or the lines based on an equation. `D3` will plot paths or lines based on co-ordinates given to it. It's your job to provide an interface between your equation and the calculation of those co-ordinates. In this answer I demonstrated a technique for converting values in your equation, to co-ordinates for a path by using the `d3.scaleLinear()` class.